# How to show empty required input field alert color as blue in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

This is my input field i make this inpufield required when this input field is empty or invalid that time it shows red alert but i want to show this input field with blue alert how it is possible ?

[image]

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Type Message" [(ngModel)]="mytext" #bigicon="ngModel" required>
  <button matSuffix mat-icon-button [disabled]="largeicon.errors && largeicon.errors.required || (bigicon.errors && bigicon.errors.required)" (click)="sendMessage()">
    <div><mat-icon style="cursor: pointer;" [inline]="true">send</mat-icon></div>
  </button>  
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I would suggest using the bootstrap framework with your project. Very easy to import and use right away.

Comment: You can either just overwrite it from your own stylesheet or for a best practice take advantage of material theming system to overwrite it. https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: @thenolin IMO, I **strongly** recommend that you **don't** use conflicting libraries with each other. The Angular Material library is supposed to be aligned with the specs anyways, so it's a better idea to customize it with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ngClass` to set the `background-color` to the color you want.

your css file

```
.custom-invalid {
  background-color: lightblue; // just use the blue you want
}
```

And your HTML file:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Type Message" [(ngModel)]="mytext" #bigicon="ngModel" required [ngClass]="{'custom-invalid': bigicon.errors || mytext === ""}">
  <button matSuffix mat-icon-button [disabled]="largeicon.errors && largeicon.errors.required || (bigicon.errors && bigicon.errors.required)" (click)="sendMessage()">
    <div><mat-icon style="cursor: pointer;" [inline]="true">send</mat-icon></div>
  </button>  
</mat-form-field>
```

This way it'll set a class with the custom background-color if the bigicon has any error or your mytext property is empty. If this `bigicon.errors` also validate if the property is empty then you don't need the `|| mytext === ""`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can change as follow -

```
/deep/ .mat-form-field.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-label{
  color: blue;
}


/deep/ .mat-form-field.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-label .mat-form-field-required-marker, /deep/ .mat-form-field.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-label.mat-accent{
   color: blue;
}

/deep/ .mat-form-field.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-ripple, /deep/ .mat-form-field.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-ripple.mat-accent{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Working demo is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-disable-file-input-on-radio-xej1gx

Comment: it make box i want to make input field with blue color

Comment: if this works with border then just adjust the css change the background-color instead.

Comment: it shows placeholder color blue but input field color line shows red

Comment: Updated the answer  and link as well.